# resd instruction in AT&T syntax

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I'm having trouble finding the equivelent operation for the "resb" instruction as outlined in the [nasm manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.2).

I've also had trouble finding equivelents to "db", "dw", etc.
They seem to be ".byte", ".short", and ".long" corresponding to "db", "dw", and "dd" respectively, but I am unsure as I've only gathered this from random code snippets. I cannot find the equivelent to "dq".

Does anyone know the proper equivelents to these pseudo-operations and possibly some reference that exhaustively lists all AT&T syntax equivlents?

Comment: For `dq` use `.quad`.  Please read [the manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the GAS manual (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) for an exhaustive list of directives it supports.  Note that the directives are basically the same across all targets that GAS supports, not specific to x86 AT&T syntax.  They have a slightly different design philosophy from NASM/YASM, but at least you don't have to re-learn them for ARM, AArch64, RISC-V, or whatever.

In general if you need to find out how to do something in GAS syntax, check the manual and/or compile some C that would need to do the same thing, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/z/QUqvL2 compiling `int foo;` in a file by itself.

**GAS syntax doesn't have an equivalent for `resw/d/q`, only [`.space` / `.skip` / `.zero`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Skip.html) for `resb`.**  The redundancy of having three synonyms for the same thing comes from GAS aiming for compatibility with assemblers provided by various historical Unix vendors.

Also, you can reserve space in the BSS *without* switching to that section with `.section .bss` (or just `.bss`) and then back, using [`.lcomm`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Lcomm.html) (non-exported symbol) or `.comm` (global symbol)

**You have to manually multiply the element count by 2/4/8 to get a byte count, like**

```
.lcomm  private_32byte_bss_object, 4*8
```

This is I think logically equivalent to `.pushsection .bss` ; `label: .space ...` ; `.popsection`

IIRC, you may need `.section .bss` if you want to use `.p2align` to give a BSS object extra alignment.  Or use the 3rd arg to `.lcommm`

> Some targets permit a third argument to be used with .lcomm. This argument specifies the desired alignment of the symbol in the bss section.

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot more sense when considering the fact that directives are common accross all platforms. I assume that ".short", and ".long" are identical to ".2byte" and ".4byte" in the case of writing x86 elfs?  And for similar reasons?

I noticed that some commands such as .intel_syntax and .att_syntax do not seem to work for me, yet no error message is returned. Do some directives not have error messages stating incorrect use, or does this simply mean its not supported?

Comment: Also, regarding switching to bss and back.  I noticed that you used .pushsection and .popsection, but could I also use .section .bss then .section .text (if I was previously in the text section)? I'm confused about whether I'm allowed to reuse sections like this.

Comment: @23scurtu: yes, you can use `.section .text` or simply `.text` if you know what section you were previously in.  I used push/pop section because I was describing exactly how `.lcomm` works in the general case.  Think of sections as multiple output streams that you can switch between, each of which will eventually end up contiguous in the `.o` object file.  (And then at link time, each section will get linked into an ELF *segment* in the executable.)

Comment: @23scurtu: `.intel_syntax noprefix` works fine for me with both GAS and clang's built-in assembler.  Did you maybe forget the `noprefix` part so the assembler was still looking for `%` decorations on register names, in a Frankenstein's monster combination of syntaxes?  And yes, you're right about .short and .long.

Comment: I tried using `.intel_syntax noprefix` again and it works now. I realized that the errors I was getting before were due to using intel syntax code that had NASM directives in it which are not supported, even if using `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  Is there a way to support nasm directives as well?

Comment: @23scurtu: no, you have to use NASM or YASM if you want to use NASM directives.  You could maybe define macros for some major like DD and DB, but if you want to write NASM syntax, just use NASM.  There are other differences, like `mov eax, symbol` in NASM is `mov r32, imm32`, but GAS is MASM-style where it's a load.  (And you need `OFFSET symbol` for its address as an immediate.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info